# How to make a CASE function return multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Us there a way to return multiple columns from the CASE function in T-SQL? The query I tried:

```
SELECT 

CASE
    WHEN Street IS NOT NULL AND City IS NOT NULL
    THEN Name, Surname, Street, City, ZipCode
    ELSE BackUpAddr
END

FROM Table
```

But as expected after "THEN" I am allowed to enter only one column. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: `CASE` is an expression that returns a **scalar** value. This logic makes even less sense with the query you have, as rows within the same dataset would have a different amount of columns; how would you expect that to look? A dataset can't have different numbers of columns per row.

Comment: TL;DR; - What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: You can perhaps concatenate the values, something like `THEN Name + Surname + ...`. Handle NULL values.

Comment: Probably I shouldn't use CASE. I will try to find different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple CASE statements for each column that you want to return:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Surname,
   CASE WHEN Street IS NOT NULL THEN Street ELSE BackUpAddr END AS 
   Street,
   CASE WHEN City IS NOT NULL THEN City ELSE BackUpAddr END AS City,
   ZipCode
FROM Table
```

Comment: Just used same conditions but different THEN cols
CASE
    WHEN Street IS NOT NULL AND City IS NOT NULL
    THEN Name
    ELSE BackUpAddr
END,
CASE
    WHEN Street IS NOT NULL AND City IS NOT NULL
    THEN Surname
    ELSE BackUpAddr
END,
CASE
    WHEN Street IS NOT NULL AND City IS NOT NULL
    THEN Street
    ELSE BackUpAddr
END

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is each option from the case expression produces a different number of results. Since this is per row, what you're asking for is results that might have varying numbers of columns. *That's not allowed.* Every row in a result set **MUST** have the same number (and type) of columns.

*You won't be able to find a way around this.* Whether you use `CASE` or something else, the columns in a result have to be consistent. No exceptions. Either you'll need to a bunch of extra `null` values for the columns in the case where you choose the `BackUpAddr` column, or you'll need to concatenate everything into a single long string for the case where you choose the other columns.

The second issue is misunderstanding that case expressions really are expressions. This is a common mistake. What this means is **a case expression is not like an `if` block in procedural code.** Instead, the result of a case expression must always be a single (scalar) value.